# Is there any alternative to each() for this scenario

Tags: loops, cypress, each

So I have a list of buttons on my webpage and I have to iterate through the list of those buttons and based on the inner text value I have to click the matching button. Now the number of buttons are dynamic, so sometimes it can be 5 or sometimes it can be 6 or something else. Now I have written a code with `each()` and this works perfectly -

```
cy.get('buton').each(($ele) => {
    if ($ele.text().trim() === "insurance") {
        cy.wrap($ele).click()
    }
})
```

My question is are there any other way this logic can be written(without using each).

Comment: Are there more than one `insurance buttons` in your page?

Answer (score 1):

You can select the button directly

```js
cy.contains('button', 'insurance').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` in combination with `contains()` to get your desired button and click it.

```
cy.get('button')
  .filter(':contains("insurance")')
  .click()
```